# Symfony api/doc route shows 404 on live server, but is OK on localhost

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, symlink, nelmioapidocbundle

I have deployed my Symfony 5 app on live server (production). I left my `.env` file with DEV variables.

Firstly my my homepage `index.php` was showing `404 URL not found on the server`, so I had to execute `ln -s public_src public` and since that my homepage was showing fine.

However I required and implemented a NelmioApiDocBundle via composer and now my API doc route `/api/doc` is working only on localhost, on live server (production) the browser says `404 URL not found on the server`.

How to fix it? Does it need another symlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the .htaccess file under public folder.